# Highchart legend over columns

Tags: highcharts, legend

is it possible in highchart to add the legend in each column with keeping
the value or label of each coulmn on top of the column like the attached image and this is my code on jsfiddle [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/4848/)
[image]

```
$('#container').highcharts({
"chart": {
    "type": "column",
        "style": {
        "fontFamily": "Arial",
            "fontSize": 12
    },
        "backgroundColor": "transparent",
        "width": 460
},

    "plotOptions": {
    "series": {
        "dataLabels": {
            "enabled": true,
                "format": "${y}"
        },
            "pointPadding": 0,
            "groupPadding": 0.1
    }
},
    "xAxis": [{

    "categories": [
        "Jan",
        "Feb",
        "Mar"],

}],

    "series": [{
    "name": "2014",
        "color": "#231E1E",
        "marker": {
        "radius": 3
    },
        "showInLegend": true,
        "connectNulls": true,
        "tooltip": [

    ],
        "data": [
    10,
    20,
    30]
}, {
    "name": "2015",
        "color": "#1DBEDE",
        "marker": {
        "radius": 3
    },
        "showInLegend": true,
        "connectNulls": true,
        "tooltip": [

    ],
        "data": [
    12,
    22,
    32]
}]
```

});

Comment: You can use [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text) to add missing text in your columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **`plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter`** instead of `format`:

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    useHTML: true,
    y: 30,
    formatter: function() {
        return "$" + this.y + "<br><br><br>" + 
               "<div style='-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); -o-transform: rotate(90deg);'>" +
               this.series.name + "</div>";
    }
}
```

You can tell the chart exactly the way you want the labels to be shown. **`this.y`** is the dollar values and **`this.series.name`** is the name of the series which are `2014` and `2015`. **`y: 30`** is where the label should be placed in respect to the top of the column. Here's a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/4850/).

PS: The problem is that you cannot have two datalabels for each column. You either have to set the location for the top label (as mentioned in my answer) or set it for the bottom labels in this [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/4852). As you can see there are some problems in each example, but you can't have both. However there could be a workaround like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/4853), but its not clean.

Comment: Thanks Raeen, you solution is almost what i want just want the year to be above Y axis directly, i ll try customize that and once i get i check you right answer.

Comment: What do you mean by above Y axis directly?

Comment: sorry i mean like the attached image , all the years inside column are in same distance from the x axis which like same margin 10 or 20 pixel

Comment: The problem is that you cannot have two datalabels for each column. You either have to set the location for the top label (as mentioned in my answer) or set it for the bottom labels in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/4852/  As you can see there are some problems in each example, but you can't have both. However there could be a workaround like this, but its not clean: http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/4853/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `stackLabels`. Of course that solution will work only when you don't use stacking at all. See demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/4855/

Code:

```
yAxis: {
    stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
            return "$" + this.total;  
        }
    }
},
"plotOptions": {
    "series": {
        stacking: "normal",
        "dataLabels": {
            "enabled": true,
            rotation: -90,
            "format": "{point.series.name}"
        },
        "pointPadding": 0,
        "groupPadding": 0.1
    }
},
```

Regarding aligning labels to the bottom, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308347/verticalalign-ignored-for-non-0-rotation).

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes on solution of @Raeen to be exactly what i want
and here is the example [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rwo7oayw/)

```
enter code jQuery('#container').highcharts({
"chart": {
    "type": "column",
        "style": {
        "fontFamily": "Arial",
            "fontSize": 12
    },
        "backgroundColor": "transparent",
        "width": 460
},
title:{
  text:''
},
tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },

    "plotOptions": {
        "series": {
            "dataLabels": {
                "inside":true,
                "enabled": true,
                useHTML: true,
                y: 30,
                formatter: function() {
                  var html ='';
                  labelHeight = this.point.shapeArgs.height-15;
                  html += '<div class="data-label-wrapper" style="height:'+labelHeight+'px;">';
                  html += '<span style="color:'+this.series.color+';">$'+this.y+'</span>';
                  html += '<span class="serie-name" style="top:'+(labelHeight-25)+'px">'+this.series.name+'</span>';
                  html += '</div>';
                 return html ;
                }
            },
                "pointPadding": 0,
                "groupPadding": 0.1
        }
},
    "xAxis": [{

    "categories": [
        "Jan",
        "Feb",
        "Mar"],

}],

    "series": [{
    "name": "2014",
        "color": "#231E1E",
        "marker": {
        "radius": 3
    },
        "showInLegend": false,
        "connectNulls": true,
        "tooltip": [

    ],
        "data": [
    10,
    20,
    30]
}, {
    "name": "2015",
        "color": "#1DBEDE",
        "marker": {
        "radius": 3
    },
        "showInLegend": false,
        "connectNulls": true,
        "tooltip": [

    ],
        "data": [
    12,
    22,
    32]
}] });
```

and now what i need if its possible to controll the number of gridlines numbers
to be like 3 instead of 8 that would be perfect.